# PHP OOP - subclasses

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, doctrine

I have the following scenario:

There is a base class called a Document and two subclasses called FileDocument and TextDocument.
FileDocument class has properties fileName, fileType and blob. TextDocument class has properties content and can have an object of FileDocument class.

The implementation will be as following:

Document

```
class Document{
 /**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="guid")
 */
private string $id;

 /**
 * @ORM\Column(name="type", type="string", length=20)
 */
private string $type;

 /**
 * @ORM\Column(name="authorName", type="string", length=20)
 */
private string $authorName

getters and settere are here
-----
-----
-----
}
```

FileDocument

```
class FileDocument extends Document {

 /**
 * @ORM\Column(name="fileName", type="string", length=20)
 */
private string $fileName;

 /**
 * @ORM\Column(name="fileType", type="string", length=20)
 */
private string $fileType;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="file", type="blob", length=20)
 */
private string $file;


public function getFileName(): string
{
    return $this->fileName;
}

public function setFileName(string $fileName): void
{
    $this->fileName = $fileName;
}

public function getContentType(): string
{
    return $this->contentType;
}

public function setContentType(string $contentType): void
{
    $this->contentType = $contentType;
}

-----
-----
-----
}
```

TextDocument

```
class TextDocument extends Document {

 /**
 * @ORM\Column(name="content", type="text", length=20)
 */
private string $content;


  /**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity=FileDocument::class)
 */
private FileDocument $file;

    
 public function getContent(): string
{
    return $this->content;
}

public function setContent(string $content): void
{
    $this->content = $content;
}

   public function getFileDocmuent(): FileDocmuent
{
    return $this->fileDocmuent;
}

public function setFileDocmuent(FileDocmuent $fileDocmuent): void
{
    $this->fileDocmuent = $fileDocmuent;
}

-----
-----
-----
}
```

Would this be possible in PHP to use subclass FileDocument in another sub class TextDocument, for example?

Comment: Yes?  Are you seeing an error?

Comment: Your class hierarchy is weird. For example, a `TextDocument` has 2 author names: one inherited from the base class and one associated with its `FileDocument`. Is it intended?

Comment: @Olivier where did you see authorName in FileDocument class?

Comment: @RobEyre It seems to me it is bad practise and performance, and want to ensure is this implementation ok?

Comment: `FileDocument` extends `Document`, so it inherits the author name.

Comment: @Olivier so the TextDocument object eventually will have one autherName that is added when the document details is added to the system. Can you explain more why you think TextDocument object will have two authorName, which I do not think it will.

Comment: If `$doc` is a `TextDocument`, then `$doc->getAuthorName()` and `$doc->getFileDocument()->getAuthorName()` will both return an author name (possibly different). If this is intended behavior, then it's fine.

Comment: @Olivier, yes, this is what I expect to calls.

Comment: Storing an object in another object isn't a problem. It's very common. If it's "bad practice" depends on who you ask. If you have some performance issues, it's most likely have to do with doctrine and how you're using it, not because of OOP in general.